# What is the best way to attribute work of third party plugins in Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am using certain plugins and code from blogs in my app. I want to know the proper way to attribute my work to them. Is the best way to create an about page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not a separate About page per se, rather tap into the Settings flyout (Windows + I key)

Take a look at some of the pre-loaded apps like Weather, Finance, and Travel, they each have an About section on the Settings panel.  The Weather app even has a separate option calling out Image Credits.

More specific guidance can be found at the [Windows Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh770544.aspx).